# create firefox profile in virtual terminal

Tags: ubuntu, bash, firefox

As part of a system setup process, I'm trying to create a default firefox profile on the command line using

`firefox -CreateProfile default`

and then proceed to customize settings, etc.

This works fine when an X server is running, but when I run my configuration script from a virtual terminal I get the error

> Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays

Is there some workaround to this so I can create the profile from a virtual terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using a virtual frame buffer:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb -y
xvfb-run firefox -CreateProfile default
```